# Null value for @EJB injection in JUnit test case

Tags: ejb-3.1

I am using WAS 8.0, EJB 3.1, CDI, and EJB embeddable container within MyEclipse 10.0. Also have beans.xml defined and embeddable container jar in classpath. Getting runtime null on EJB reference (Course) in the test class.

public class CourseTest extends TestCase {

```
@EJB    
private Course course;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext().bind("inject", this);
}

@Test
public void test() {

    // Was the EJB injected?
    assertTrue(course != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your testcase class is not constructed by the container, so injection will not be performed.  You'll need to manually look up the EJB from `EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext()`.

(As an aside, the EJBContainer API only allows one active EJB container per process.  I would suggest storing the result of `EJBContainer.createEJBContainer()` in a field and closing it from an `@After` method.)